# Read Xml Array of String and load it into List(Of String

Tags: xml, vb.net, xmlhttprequest, xml-serialization

I am trying to read Xml data and load it into List of String. However I am not able to get it done. Here is my code below.

Dim result As String = ""

```
    Dim soap As String = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>" & vbCr & vbLf & "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" " & vbCr & vbLf & "   xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" " & vbCr & vbLf & "   xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">" & vbCr & vbLf & "  <soap:Body>" & vbCr & vbLf & "    <Register xmlns=""http://tempuri.org/"">" & vbCr & vbLf & "      <id>123</id>" & vbCr & vbLf & "      <data1>string</data1>" & vbCr & vbLf & "    </Register>" & vbCr & vbLf & "  </soap:Body>" & vbCr & vbLf & "</soap:Envelope>"

    Dim req As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:59924/WebService.asmx/HelloWorld"), HttpWebRequest)
    req.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", """http://tempuri.org/Register""")
    req.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=""utf-16"""
    req.Accept = "text/xml"
    req.Method = "POST"
    'req.ContentLength = strCritera.Length
    req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008070208 Firefox/3.0.1"
    req.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"

    Dim requestWriter As New StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream())
    requestWriter.Close()

    Dim responseReader As New StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
    Dim responseData As String = responseReader.ReadToEnd()

    Dim fileName As String = responseData

    Dim doc As New XmlDocument()

    doc.LoadXml(fileName)

    Dim categories As New List(Of String)()

    Dim nList As XmlNodeList = doc.SelectNodes("/ArrayOfString/string")

    For Each node As XmlNode In nList
        categories.Add(node.ToString())
    Next
```

I am getting nList with 0 count.
Below is the xml data I am getting from the web service.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <string>Test1</string>
  <string>Test2</string>
  <string>Test3</string>
  <string>Test4</string>
  <string>Test5</string>
  <string>Test7</string>
</ArrayOfString>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because the xml has default namespace (`xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"`), so you'll need to use prefix in `XPath` query and use `XmlNamespaceManager` to define the prefix :

```
.....
Dim namespaceManager As XmlNamespaceManager = New XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable)
namespaceManager.AddNamespace("d", "http://tempuri.org/")
Dim nList As XmlNodeList = doc.SelectNodes("/d:ArrayOfString/d:string", namespaceManager)
......
```

When prefix is not supplied in XPath query it will be considered as element with no namespace. And in XML, when the file has default namespace declared, all element without prefix will be considered as in default namespace [[Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp)].